# Is there a way to get all items off a merchant before I kill them in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Sorry for my poor English. I live in non English-speaking country.

It seems that all items in the merchant's stock disappear when I kill him/her, so I can only obtain what's in his/her pocket.

Of course, if I buy all items from the merchant before the slaughter, I can get not only all items but also the caps I used to buy those stuffs. However, I can't buy all items because they are too expensive.

(For example, Gloria Van Graff sells lots of things from GRA, and GRA's stuffs costs me a fortune.)

Is there a way to get all items of merchant before I kill him/her not using console commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, most of the times merchant inventory is stored in an external inaccessible container.

Here is the relevant quote from the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_merchants):

> Most merchant inventories are stocked using external containers stored in a hidden cell which refreshes their contents every three days. However, in some instances merchants will have their container stored in a different cell, often the same cell they are in. If the container is not properly flagged as a quest item it will not refresh its contents unless the player is in the same cell. Gloria Van Graff and Torres are affected by this issue.